# Modify class list for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I modify the class list via jQuery or JavaScript for multiple classes in one step?

I have several classes in my form like

```
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">...</div>
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">...</div>
<div class="form-group has-error has-feedback">...</div>
```

How can I remove all the classes except `form-group`?

```
<div class="form-group">...</div>
<div class="form-group">...</div>
<div class="form-group">...</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) method.

```
$(".form-group.has-error.has-feedback").removeClass("has-error has-feedback");
```

From the jQuery Documentation:

> **Description:**
>
> Remove a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each
> element in the set of matched elements.
>
> ...
>
> If a class name is included as a parameter, then only that class will be removed from the set of matched elements. If no class names are specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this (removing class from multiple elements) using javascript's `classList.remove`?

Answer (score 2):

**JQuery**

You can do it using `attr` function :

```
$('div.form-group.has-error.has-feedback').attr('class', 'form-group');
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

For javascript you can use `querySelector` and `setAttribute()` function :

```
document.querySelector('div.form-group.has-error.has-feedback').setAttribute('class', 'form-group');
```

Hope this helps.